# How can I check(checkV) if a value exists in Binary search tree if does I output "true" else "false"

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

How can I check(checkV) if a value exists in Binary search tree if does I output "true" else "false"

```cpp
void search(Node* root, int checkV){

    if(checkV > root->data){
        search(root->right, checkV);
    }
    if(checkV < root->data){
        search(root->left, checkV);
    }
    if(checkV == root->data){
        cout << "true"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "false"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Looks ok at the first glance.

Comment: It'll give an error when the node we are looking for with the given ```int``` value is not found. We have to add the ```nullptr``` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use function "search", then first you should check if root points the nullptr, then if you found data and only after that you should search. Something like this:

```
void search(Node* root, int checkV) {

    if (root->data == nullptr) {
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
    else if (checkV == root->data) {
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }
    else if (checkV > root->data) {
        search(root->right, checkV);
    }
    else {
        search(root->left, checkV);
    }
}
```

But it would be better, if you return bool from search and print result according to that

```
bool search(Node *root, int checkV) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return false;
    if (root->data == checkV)
        return true;
    return root->data < checkV ? check(root->left, checkV) : check(root->right, checkV);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to modify your function so that it returns `bool` variables. To implement the function properly, think about the cases in which you don't find the node you are looking for. In such cases, eventually you will get a `nullptr`, that is `Node* root` won't point to an existing object. You can construct the `if-else` blocks as below.

```cpp
bool search(Node* root, int checkV){
    if(root == nullptr) return false;
    else if(checkV > root->data) return search(root->right, checkV);
    else if(checkV < root->data) return search(root->left, checkV);
    else if(checkV == root->data) return true;  // you can use else as well
}

// Print out true if node exists, otherwise false.
cout << search(root, 5) << endl;
```

Comment: The recursive calls need to be returned. i.e `return search(...)`.